# Jetpack Compose - rememberCoroutineScope but with keys

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

How can I obtain a coroutine scope bound to a composable but also to some key values? Basically I want to obtain something like this:

```
@Composable
fun Sth(val sth: Int) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope(sth)
}
```

I need the scope to be canceled when the call leaves the composition (just like with `rememberCoroutineScope`), but also when the key `sth` changes.

Update:

One place in which I need this functionality:

```
class SomeIndication(
    val a: Int,
    val b: Int
) : Indication {

    @Composable
    override fun rememberUpdatedInstance(interactionSource: InteractionSource): IndicationInstance {
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope(interactionSource)
        return remember(interactionSource) {
            val sth: State<Int> = sth(a, b, coroutineScope)
            object: IndicationInstance {
                override fun ContentDrawScope.drawIndication() {
                    drawContent()
                    drawSomething(x.value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, I currently developed my own solution. Let me know what you think about it. Feels weird that it is not possible by default.

```
@Composable
inline fun rememberCoroutineScope(
    key: Any,
    crossinline getContext: @DisallowComposableCalls () -> CoroutineContext = { Dispatchers.Main }
) =
    remember(key) { CoroutineWrapper(getContext()) }

class CoroutineWrapper(
    coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
) : RememberObserver, CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext = coroutineContext + Job()
    override fun onAbandoned() {
        cancel("Left composition")
    }
    override fun onForgotten() {
        cancel("Left composition")
    }
    override fun onRemembered() { }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect):

```
@Composable
fun Sth(val sth: Int) {
    // `LaunchedEffect` will cancel and re-launch if `sth` changes
    LaunchedEffect(sth) {
        // call suspend functions
    }
}
```

> When `LaunchedEffect` enters the Composition, it launches a coroutine
> with the block of code passed as a parameter. The coroutine will be
> cancelled if `LaunchedEffect` leaves the composition. If
> LaunchedEffect is recomposed with different keys, the existing
> coroutine will be cancelled and the new suspend function will be
> launched in a new coroutine.

---

Or try to wrap launching a coroutine with a `LaunchedEffect`:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

LaunchedEffect(key1 = sth) {
    // will be canceled and re-launched if sth is changed
    coroutineScope.launch() {
        // call suspend functions
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it can help me. I need to pass the `coroutineScope` as a parameter to a method that's called into a `remember` scope.

Comment: Could you post an example in your question?

Comment: I added an example. Now that I think more of it, maybe I could end up creating a coroutine scope in that remember scope?

Comment: I've added an update: I assume you launch a coroutine using `coroutineScope` in the `sth` function, then maybe you can wrap the call to `coroutineScope.launch()` with `LaunchedEffect` in that function and it might give you the behavior you want.

Comment: I don't think `coroutineScope.launch` cares about the place from where we call it :/

Comment: @Sergio I would love to provide my example but its a a bit tight in a comment. I have a composable view that represents posts. On a button press the user triggers an async operation. If the user leaves the post, I want to cancel that operation. If he leaves to a different screen, that works fine with `rememberCoroutineScope`. However the user can also navigate to the next post, and then the "post" composable remains in the composition and so does the coroutineScope. So I need to have a `rememberCoroutineScope` that cancels when they key (postId) changes.